# ESP8266-01 not working at all, with AT firmware or blink sketch

Tags: at-command, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I have worked a lot to make these modules work, but they don't.

Module : ESP8266 ESP-01
[Module image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkekQ.jpg)

I uploaded several versions of AT firmware with different methods and and softwares and tested sending AT command with different softwares. but I get nothing in response.
Then I tried Arduino IDE and uploaded blink example for GPIO2 and it's not working too.

LED just remains off after reset in normal mode.
I tried with just turning it on and not blink, with setting GPIO2 on LOW but the same result. I tested with external LED on GPIO2 too with a 100 ohm resistor.

I have 2 modules and tested both of them.

For now I just go with blink example details to make things simple.

connections:

- VCC (pin8) : 3.3 V (tested both USB and external power)
- GND (pin1) : GND
- CH_PD (pin4) : 3.3 V
- RESET (pin6) : pulled up with 10k resistor. and GND pulse for changing mode.
- TXD (pin2) : usb2serial module RXD
- RXD (pin7) : usb2serial module TXD
- GPIO0 (pin5) : connected to GND for uploading, float for testing.
- GPIO2 (pin3) : tested with nothing and also with external LED.

I use ch140 usb2serial module for connection to laptop. and it's recognized on COM3.
Its GND is connected to breadboard's GND.
I tested both 3.3 from USB and from external power supply.
To go in upload mode I connect GPIO0 to GND and a GND pulse to RESET.
Then for normal mode disconnect GPIO0 and pulse GND to RESET.
I tested with another method too.

Both 2 modules can upload firmware and code fine but not working.
Blue led (GPIO2) blinks while uploading.

code :

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);     // Initialize the LED_BUILTIN pin as an output
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
  // but actually the LED is on; this is because
  // it is active low on the ESP-01)
  delay(1000);                      // Wait for a second
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
  delay(2000);                      // Wait for two seconds (to demonstrate the active low LED)
}
```

code tested with both LED_BUILTIN word and number 2.

[IDE settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P43zA.jpg)

also tested with a few other settings like Flash size and Flash mode and Reset Method.

[IDE and Upload result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjGWf.jpg)

Upload result text:

```
Executable segment sizes:


IROM   : 227612          - code in flash         (default or ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR) 


IRAM   : 26776   / 32768 - code in IRAM          (ICACHE_RAM_ATTR, ISRs...) 


DATA   : 1252  )         - initialized variables (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


RODATA : 672   ) / 81920 - constants             (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


BSS    : 24880 )         - zeroed variables      (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


Sketch uses 256312 bytes (26%) of program storage space. Maximum is 958448 bytes.
Global variables use 26804 bytes (32%) of dynamic memory, leaving 55116 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
esptool.py v2.8
Serial port COM3
Connecting....
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
Crystal is 26MHz
MAC: 2c:3a:e8:0c:18:c9
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Configuring flash size...
Auto-detected Flash size: 1MB
Erasing flash (this may take a while)...
Chip erase completed successfully in 5.3s
Compressed 260464 bytes to 190653...

Writing at 0x00000000... (8 %)
Writing at 0x00004000... (16 %)
Writing at 0x00008000... (25 %)
Writing at 0x0000c000... (33 %)
Writing at 0x00010000... (41 %)
Writing at 0x00014000... (50 %)
Writing at 0x00018000... (58 %)
Writing at 0x0001c000... (66 %)
Writing at 0x00020000... (75 %)
Writing at 0x00024000... (83 %)
Writing at 0x00028000... (91 %)
Writing at 0x0002c000... (100 %)
Wrote 260464 bytes (190653 compressed) at 0x00000000 in 16.9 seconds (effective 123.3 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.

Leaving...
Soft resetting...
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: pull-up io 0 over a resistor for normal boot

Comment: @Juraj I tested it but the result was the same. thanks

Comment: Are you sure your LED pin is GPIO 2? Some ESP 01 modules use [different pins](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/3165). I have a black ESP 01 and it flashes blue when I `digitalWrite(1, ...)`. For my board, this is the TX pin and is the one that blinks while uploading.